# How to fix type inference for a component variable in a jest Mount test built with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, type-inference, mount

My scenario is a react project built in typescript, and specifically regarding a unit test involving `mount` from Enzyme. I'm working on aligning the project with the tsconfig parameter "noImplicitAny": true, I'm wondering how to fix the let component issue described under.

```
let wrapper

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(<Component/>)
})

it('shows the rendered component', () => {
  expect(wrapper.find('.class-component')).toHaveLength(1)
})
```

and error is:

```
Variable 'wrapper' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.ts (7034)
```

How to create the inference of type `Component` to variable component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `mount(<Component/>)` is `ReactWrapper`. you can just explicitly set the type for wrapper when declaring.

```
import { ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';

let wrapper: ReactWrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(<Component/>) // ts will no longer infer the type for wrapper as any
})
```

Similarly `ShallowWrapper` can be used as the type for the wrapper when using shallow rendering. Keep in mind both `ReactWrapper` and `ShallowWrapper` are generic, so you can also provide additional type information for the component as type arguments.